# Visual Studio Community 2022 - Server Error related to App_GlobalResourcesLang.resources

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resx, app-globalresources

We created a multi-language C# .NET webform website in Visual Studio Community 2022.

When the website is browsed in the computers with Visual Studio installed, everything is fine. However, when the website is browsed in the computers without Visual Studio, there is an error:

> Server Error in '/dev/websitename' Application. Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources
> appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make
> sure "ProjectName.App_GlobalResources.Lang.resources" was correctly
> embedded or linked into assembly "ProjectName" at compile time, or
> that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
> signed.]
> System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String
> fileName) +441
> System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo
> culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean
> createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1219
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
> requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1008
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
> requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1008
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
> culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents) +43
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo
> culture) +567 Projectname.filename.funcationname() in
> C:\Users\Path\filename.aspx.cs:80
> System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +108
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +90
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +1533 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4330.0

The function causes the error that gets the text to show based on the language selected.
In the function, the scripts are:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Lang"].ToString());
rm = new ResourceManager("ProjectName.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

The properties of the languages resx files are:

1. Build Action:  Embedded Resources
2. Custom Tool: GlobalResourceProxyGenerator
3. Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

We tried

1. Change the setting to : Copy if newer
2. Use a new resx files
   but still failed.

Is there any way we can solve this error?
Many Thanks

Comment: Please use `dotPeek` to check whether your resources are actually embedded inside the assembly returned from `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. Also, does this happen on the neutral culture or a specific culture?

Comment: Also, why are you creating a new .NET Framework Web Forms application in 2022? Web Forms is still supported, but [will be phased out when the operating systems that come with .NET Framework 4.8 installed reach end of support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/aspnet). Furthermore, there is [no easy migration path to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/migrate-web-forms) for Web Forms.